# How do I configure vscode to use the same (linux) file path format as WSL?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, filepath, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The File->Open command will show Windows' Explorer dialog screen and thus uses Windows file path format, `C:\abc\xyz`. However, I'd like the command to work with Linux file path, e.g., `/home/foo/test.py`. Is that possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need the vscode extension "Remote - WSL" installed which will enable a little green box in bottom left corner.

Clicking it will give you the option to "Remote-WSL: Reopen Folder in WSL" | Select WSL distro, e.g. Ubuntu.

note 1 - details on this is also covered in https://code.visualstudio.com/remote-tutorials/wsl/run-in-wsl

note 2 - it may not be required but i'm running with wsl2 tech preview update inplace [ "windows wsl2 docker setup" | past year -> https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/ ]. I have it in place to enable docker service to be hosted using new wsl vm versus outgoing hyper-v vm approach. Don't think its required for vscode wsl integration to work.

[image]